# How to call methods inside a class?

Tags: python

I have a test Python class named calc with two methods `add` and `sub`. How can I run the methods from the python prompt? I am at the python command line ">>>" and typing `import calc`. Then I type `calc.add(5,3)` and get "No module named 'calc'". File name is `calc.py`.

```
class calc:

    def add(x,y):
        answer = x + y
        print(answer)

    def sub(x,y):
        answer = x - y
        print(answer)
```

Comment: Just define them as standalone functions. Neither of those functions require any state from the `calc` class. Then what you are currently doing will work. The class is pretty much redundant.

Answer (score 2):

`calc` is the module name *and* a class in the module. Use `import calc` and then refer to the class with `calc.calc`:

`calc.py`:

```
class calc:

    def add(self, x, y): # note the use of "self"
        answer = x + y
        print(answer)

    def sub(self, x, y):
        answer = x - y
        print(answer)
```

Test script:

```
import calc
c = calc.calc()
c.add(5, 3)
```

Several modules in the standard library exhibit this naming scheme, such as `pprint`, `time`, and `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you but this is the print out I'm getting with the above.   Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:27:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import calc
>>> c = calc.calc()
>>> c.add(5,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
>>>

Comment: @martinbshp - Note the comment in the code block for `calc.py`. That change resolves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `calc` class from your `calc` module:

```
from calc import calc # we're importing only calc class from that module

c = calc()
c.add(5,3)
```